# Django Automated Testing doesn't work with heroku postgresql database

Tags: django, heroku, django-testing, django-tests, django-postgresql

I made a Django app from the tutorial using a postgresql database. The automated testing worked fine when my app was running locally.  I have since deployed it to heroku and when I try to run the tests I get this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: Normally Django will use a connection to the 
'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against
the production database when it's not needed (for example, when 
running tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 
'postgres' database and will use the default database instead.
RuntimeWarning

Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create
database
```

I've searched far and wide and haven't found a solution to this.  My app otherwise works fine.  It has no issues reading from the database.  It just won't run my tests.

The only way I've found to make my tests work is to manually copy and paste the database credentials for my local database into settings.py and then change them back after my tests are run but thats a silly solution to this.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Why would you run your tests on Heroku?

Comment: did you find a solution for your issue ?

Comment: Still no solution?